# Is there a bug with Xcode 9.3 affecting Cordova Run iOS (in simulator)?

Tags: xcode, cordova

My Cordova iOS builds had previously been running fine from the CLI, until I updated to macOS 10.13.4 and Xcode 9.3 (9E145).  Now whenever I use

```
cordova run ios
```

The simulator will launch, but my app is not installed or run, and this message is displayed:

```
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
```

After a minute or two, the process stops and the message then reads:

```
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
The request to open "com.myapp.name" failed.
The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: NotFound ("Application "com.myapp.name" is unknown to FrontBoard").
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=4):
    The operation couldn’t be completed. Application "com.myapp.name" is unknown to FrontBoard.
    Application "com.myapp.name" is unknown to FrontBoard.
```

Has anyone encountered this message specifically after installing Xcode 9.3?  I've uninstalled and reinstalled Cordova, I've tried 'erase settings' within the simulator, and I've removed and added the iOS platform from my project.
The project will successfully build and run if I open the Xcode project file directly within Xcode.  So currently it just seems to be a fault from launching the simulator from the Cordova CLI.
Any other tips/tricks?

Comment: I've since uninstalled and reinstalled both Cordova and Xcode.  Still getting the error, still unable to launch apps into the similar from the command line.

Comment: Did you try using these commands?
phonegap platform remove ios
phonegap platform add ios

Comment: Sorry Jason, that did not work either.

Comment: Try removing the spaces in the project path (if you have one).

Answer (score 0):

I’m having a similar issue.

seeing this after I update to XCode 9.3 and build through cli
Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 “No profiles for ‘org.oclc.digby’ were found” UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for ‘org.oclc.digby’ were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn’t find any iOS Ad Hoc provisioning profiles matching ‘org.oclc.digby’. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.}
When I bring the project up in XCode the signing is correct and not complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, solved after install iOS 11.2 Simulator in Xcode preferences -> Components, then

```
ionic cordova run ios -l --target="iPhone-X"
```

Comment: I was really hoping that would solve my problem, but unfortunately still getting the same error message even after installing iOS 11.2.

Comment: sad to read that :( are you sure that simulator is set to ios 11.2?